# Installing UEFI Updates On Ubuntu Installation Legacy BOOT

Tags: dual-boot, uefi, 17.10

I have just installed Ubuntu 17.10.1 on an external hard drive (Seagate Expansion 2TB) because the internal SSD on this machine (Dell XPS 9350) is too small to dual boot it alongside my Windows installation. In order to do this I have run my Dell in Legacy Boot mode. 
Now Ubuntu is requesting to install UEFI updates:
[image: Ubuntu is requesting to install UEFI updates]
Is this wise considering I am booting in legacy mode? I don't want to put Windows at risk.
Many thanks

Comment: Not  sure what it is updating, but it does not look like it is converting to UEFI, just some UEFI drivers to better see your UEFI system. With your Dell you can install in UEFI mode. But have to partition with gpt in advance and best to include an ESP on external even if not immediately used. http://askubuntu.com/questions/743095/how-to-prepare-a-disk-on-an-efi-based-pc-for-ubuntu Often easiest to unplug internal drive, but not required. http://askubuntu.com/questions/743095/how-to-prepare-a-disk-on-an-efi-based-pc-for-ubuntu

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I used gparted to manually partition this drive, I never saw an option to include ESP. How would I do this?

Comment: First link I posted above. It is the FAT32 partition, but when you add boot flag it converts it to the ESP. If using gdisk it is code ef00. The actual gpt(GUID) type code is a very long string of numbers, so different partitioning tools use different methods to assign codes.